# Grabbing URL with nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, web, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I'm trying to grab some information from a website, I have a script I've written and edited for a few different websites but this one in-particular is causing me grief!

The script reads through the categories and builds an array or pages to open, then goes ahead and opens each page, it's then supposed to grab info from each product on each category page. The functionality of building the array is still working fine, it just seems the markup is so different on this website it reacts differently.

I need to read from this markup

```
<li>
        <a class="product-link" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl_1">
            <img class='product_image' src="image/path_1.jpg" title=""  alt="PRODUCT NAME"  /></a>

        <a class="product-title" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl_1">PRODUCT NAME 1</a>

        <span>PRICE</span>
    </li><!----><li>
    <a class="product-link" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl_2">
        <img class='product_image' src="image/path_2.jpg" title=""  alt="PRODUCT NAME 2"  /></a>

    <a class="product-title" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl">PRODUCT NAME 2</a>

    <span>PRICE</span>
</li><!----><li>
    <a class="product-link" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl_3">
        <img class='product_image' src="image/path_3.jpg" title=""  alt="PRODUCT NAME 3"  /></a>

    <a class="product-title" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl_3">PRODUCT NAME 3</a>

    <span>PRICE</span>
</li><!----><li>
    <a class="product-link" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl">
        <img class='product_image' src="image/path.jpg" title=""  alt="PRODUCT NAME"  /></a>

    <a class="product-title" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl">PRODUCT NAME</a>

    <span>PRICE</span>
</li>
```

My script;

Each product is within a `<li>` tag

```
page.css('li').each do |product|
  # ...
end
```

I can pick up the product name with

```
product.css('.product-title').text.strip
```

Then usually to grab the product URL I'd define the tags the URL is within and use something like this to grab the contents of the href and the gsub to get rid of the newline

```
product.css('.product-title')[:href].gsub(/\n/,"")
```

In this case, I'm getting

```
./script.rb:52:in []: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
    from ./script.rb:52:in block in <main>
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in block in each
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in upto
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in each
    from ./script.rb:39:in <main>
```

How can I get it to read the `href`? I can't work out why it's throwing this error, when it usually works with different websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product.css('.product-title')` returns a [`NodeSet`](http://rdoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet), similar to an array.

Either use [`first`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#first-instance_method) or [`[0]`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#%5B%5D-instance_method) to get the first element:

```
product.css('.product-title').first['href'] #=> "http://www.DOMAIN/producturl"
product.css('.product-title')[0]['href']    #=> "http://www.DOMAIN/producturl"
```

or the [`at_css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#at_css-instance_method) shortcut:

```
product.at_css('.product-title')['href']    #=> "http://www.DOMAIN/producturl"
```

A more complete example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(<<-HTML)
<li>
  <a class="product-link" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl">
    <img class='product_image' src="image/path.jpg" title=""  alt="PRODUCT NAME"  />
  </a>
  <a class="product-title" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl">PRODUCT NAME</a>
  <span>PRICE</span>
</li>
HTML

page.css('li').each do |product|
  puts product.at_css('.product-title')['href']
end
```

Output:

```
http://www.DOMAIN/producturl
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, I've actually tried the `at_css` option but it returns this error;

`./script.rb:52:in block in <main>: undefined method [] for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

I get the same error with the first suggestion also.

Comment: @James this is because `css('.product-title')` returns an empty `NodeSet`, i.e. there is no element with `class="product-title"`. You could add a condition: `if product.at_css('.product-title') ...`

Comment: The element does exist, I'm actually able to grab the text from the product-title class with no problem.

Comment: I can't help you without seeing the actual HTML.

Comment: It's like so, it's formatted better up in the initial question;

`<li>
        <a class="product-link" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl">
            <img class='product_image' src="image/path.jpg" title=""  alt="PRODUCT NAME"  /></a>

        <a class="product-title" href="http://www.DOMAIN/producturl">PRODUCT NAME</a>

        <span>PRICE</span>
    </li>`

Comment: I've updated my question. Not sure why this is not working for you.

Comment: Yeah, it's really strange, this is the first thing I've built in Ruby so I'm really new to it but everything I've read + what you're saying indicates it should work.

This is somewhat working for me `page.css('.product-title')[0]['href']` although, it grabs the first instance only and ignores the other products on the page, do you know of a way I can get it to do for each `href`?

Comment: The HTML you've posted contains only one product. If your actual HTML looks different, you have to show it (or a link to it). Edit your question and add the relevant details.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more products, the script needs to grab the url and title for each.

Comment: Pasting your HTML into my script outputs all four URLs.

Comment: Your suggestion is definitely working on it's own (it will grab that tag), not alongside putting my links array, I think it's down to the different markup on the site, I've had to go for a change of approach with this one (which I couldn't achieve without your suggestion). Thanks very much for your help.